# Dependency injection using IOC (Inversion of Control)

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, nullreferenceexception

**I've Interface**

```
 public interface IDatabase
 {
        void AddRow(string table, string value);
 }
```

**It's implemented on**

```
 public class Database : IDatabase
 {
     public void AddRow(string table,string value)
     {

     }
 }
```

**Now here I'm doing Dependency Injection**

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
     private readonly IDatabase _database;
     private readonly string ss;
     public CustomerRepository()
     {

     }
     public CustomerRepository(IDatabase database)
     {
        this._database = database;
     }
     public void Add(string customer,string table)
     {
        _database.AddRow(customer, table);
     }
}
```

**I'm accessing `Add` method of `CustomerRepository` from below class**

```
public class Access
{
    CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
    public void InsertRecord()
    {
        customerRepository.Add("customer", "name");
    }
}
```

> Now When I call `Add` method of `CustomerRepository` class then I'm getting `_database` null.

Comment: You should provide ```IDatabase``` object when you initiate the ```CustomerRepository```

Comment: @MartinSiagian How can i provide `IDatabase` to `CustomerRepository`

Comment: My first question is why you have to create ```Database``` class in the first place?? You can inherit ```CustomerRepository``` from ```IDatabase```
It's a bit DRY for me

Comment: Yes, It just separation of classes. Agree with you

Comment: Prevent having multiple constructors. [Having multiple constructors is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: And add a guard check `if (database == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("database"); }` so it cannot be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now here I'm doing Dependency Injection

Yes, you're using the dependency injection, but you're calling *the wrong constructor*:

```
CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
```

Your class has an empty constructor as well, which doesn't accept an `IDatabase`. Hence, you don't provide it when you instantiate your class, and that's why it's null.

You could *not use* injection by supplying the `IDatabase` concrete type directly:

```
CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(new ConcreteDatabase());
```

But, If you started working with DI, I'm not sure that's the path you'll want to go with.

In order for that to work *properly*, you can inject `CustomRepository` to `Access` and register all the dependencies via a IOC container.

```
public class Access
{
    private readonly CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    public Access(CustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }
}
```

That's the way it works with dependency injection. Once you start injecting to once class, you inject the others as well, and that is how your object dependency graph gets resolved by the container, at run-time.

Comment: Now how can i initialize object for `Access` class. Could you please add implementation for `Access` class?

Comment: @RahulNikate Do you have a IOC container? Do you use any external tool for doing your dependency injection?

Comment: Thank for your help. It's really helpful. Could you please tell me about IOC container? How dependencies will get resolved using IOC container? IOC container is there in my project but not aware how it's been implemented.

Comment: I would suggest you start by reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx). Dependency injection is a big subject to get into in a SO question.

Comment: I think we have `AutoFac`

Comment: Then start [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much @Yuval Itzchakov for helping me.